# Check if button is active then get its value to pass down a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[image]

```
function Input() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  function handleSearch() {
    let url = "https://google.com/search?q=${input}"
    window.open(url)
  }
  return (
    <div className="input-wrap">
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input__search"
        placeholder="Enter your search..."
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
      <button
        className="input__search--btn"
        onClick={handleSearch}>
        <i className="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The search button when clicked will redirect you to a google search based on the value from the input field, below is the site for advanced search, when active the link will add an additional link after `"https://google.com/search?q=${input}+site%3A${activepage}.com`, how do I check if one or many sites are active then pass down its name to `url`

P/s: code for toggling websites

```
function WebButton({ icon, name }) {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    function handleToggle() {
        setActive(!active);
    }
        return (
            <button
            className={active ? "websites-btn active" : "websites-btn"}
            onClick={handleToggle}>
            <i className={icon}></i>
            <div className="websites-name">{name}</div> 
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do and which button you are talking about based on the picture? Are you trying to select a search engine and then use the top search to search on your input req?

Comment: The search button, I'm trying to filter out the active sites below, if they're active I need to pass their name to the URL so I can search with that specific site, i.e if StackOverflow is active the URL would be https://google.com/search?q={input}+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Since knowing which sites are selected is important to this part of your application, this information should be part of the state of an ancestor component, not be local to the button itself. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a root level state to gather active links to a state. And pass it to the `Input` component.

1. Update your `Input` component to accept array called `` and update the `handleSearch` to use `OR` operation in google search.

```
function Input({ activeLinks }) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  function handleSearch() {
    if (activeLinks.length > 0) {
      let compundSearchURL = `https://google.com/search?q=${input}`;
      activeLinks.forEach((link, i) => {
        compundSearchURL += `+${i > 0 ? "OR+" : ""}site%3A${link}.com`;
      });
      window.open(compundSearchURL);
    } else {
      window.open(`https://google.com/search?q=${input}`);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="input-wrap">
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input__search"
        placeholder="Enter your search..."
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
      <button className="input__search--btn" onClick={handleSearch}>
        <i className="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass">Search</i>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. Accept another function in `WebButton` called `toggleActiveLink` and a string called `value` which refers to the URL part. Call the function with the value inside `handleToggle` function.

```
function WebButton({ icon, name, toggleActiveLink, value }) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  function handleToggle() {
    setActive(!active);
    toggleActiveLink(value);
  }
  return (
    <button
      className={active ? "websites-btn active" : "websites-btn"}
      style={{ color: active ? "blue" : "unset" }}
      onClick={handleToggle}
    >
      <i className={icon}></i>
      <div className="websites-name">{name}</div>
    </button>
  );
}
```

3. In the main component you have to create a local state to handle the active links. Create the toggle function as given. It will add the value if it is not there otherwise remove it.

```
const urls = [
  { name: "Reddit", value: "reddit" },
  { name: "Quora", value: "quara" },
  { name: "Facebook", value: "facebook" },
  { name: "Stackoverflow", value: "stackoverflow" },
  { name: "Twitter", value: "twitter" }
];

function App() {
  const [activeLinks, setActiveLinks] = useState([]);

  const toggleActiveLink = (link) => {
    const index = activeLinks.indexOf(link);
    if (index < 0) {
      setActiveLinks((prevLinks) => [...prevLinks, link]);
    } else {
      setActiveLinks((prevLinks) => prevLinks.filter((l) => l !== link));
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Input activeLinks={activeLinks} />
      <div>
        {urls.map(({ name, value }) => (
          <WebButton
            name={name}
            value={value}
            toggleActiveLink={toggleActiveLink}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit mutli site google search react]

Comment: @Andrew Elking, check this out !!